# SPDataAccess Role is not visible - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sql-server

I have a Sharepoint 2013 farm and SPDataAccess Role is available for some content DBs and not for others. Is there a way to add this role to a specific DB using PowerShell?

[image]

Comment: are these new dbs(created in 2013) or migrated from sp2010?

Comment: I am migrating from 2013 but before me they could have been migrated from 2010 to 2013.

Comment: are you checking the content db or services db( i.e upa / search etc), and also which account you are looking for( farm admin or something else)

Comment: this is a content db. I am not sure if I understand what you mean by checking?

Comment: i checked my dev farm, this role is avaiable for all Content DB attached to sharepoint 2013 farm and i cant see the shell access role on any of them....so question is, areThese DBs attached to SP 2013 or some attached to SP2010?

Comment: These DBs were attached to 2013. And I am moving them to a new 2013 farm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24459/discussion-between-aslan-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).